# Revised Question: How do I prevent Oracle 12c Database from starting on machine boot

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I'd posted previously about `srvctl`, didn't realize it was only used if a Grid Infrastructure was installed, which in my case, is not.

Anyways, I have Oracle 12c Database installed on my Windows 8.1 pro personal machine, used for testing purposes (school work actually).  As such, I don't want it to be up every time I log into my PC.  And being forced to run `SQL shutdown` every time I've logged in is a hassle (I realize I could write a batch script but that's a last resort).

I can't figure out what service is starting an Oracle Instance at boot.  Does anyone know of what does?  I've been combing through the Oracle Doc's and can't seem to find out what it is.

TL;DR:  Just trying to stop my Oracle Database from initializing on a PC boot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to prevent the `OracleService<<SID>>` from starting automatically.  Assuming you used the default SID of `ORCL`, that would be OracleServiceORCL.

You'll likely also see a number of other services that start with `Oracle` that are for various other components (i.e. your listener, your MTS recovery service, etc.)  You can set all those to not start automatically if you want.  Given that those services tend to use many fewer resources, it's generally easiest to let them run to make it easier to start the database later on.

Answer (score 3):

You have two solution:

1. In Windows OS's in the run, type services.msc and Enter,from the list of services find ***OracleService*<*SID name*>** and right click and choose Properties. In General tab in the Startup Type section choose Manual and click OK and exit.
   From now on your database doesn't start automatically by your machine's start, but whenever you want to start it you have to go to services.msc and start it manually.You can also do this from Windows Task Manager(from Services tab).
2. Let the Startup Type to be *automatic* in "services.msc". Open Windows
   command prompt (Admin) and type this statement (instead of ORCL use
   your SID name).Answer of [this topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101793/startup-oracle-database-12c-manually-with-sqlplus-command-not-when-os-loads-so).
   `oradim -edit -sid ORCL -startmode manual`
   Now your database is in a state that idiomatically called *idle*. You can start your database by logging to SQL*Plus with sysdba privilege and then type `startup` command.