# Startup oracle database 12c manually with SQL*Plus command not when OS loads

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I changed oracle instance to manually start from *services.msc* (service name is "OracleServiceORCL"), Because I want to start it up manually with SQL*Plus commands whenever I want, not with OS load.

Now I can't do that in SQL*Plus and I got this error:

> ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

So I start it manually from *services.msc* and when database got ready I shut it down with SQL*Plus command. After that I realize that the service is still running, with very low consuming of resources.

I think this called "*idle instance*".

How can I automatically be in an *idle instance* state after I logged in to my Windows 8.1 to start oracle database whenever I want with SQL*Plus commands, not manually from *services.msc*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure this behaviour through the [Administration Assistant](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTQRF/tools.htm#i1006857), where you can choose to start (or not to start) the database instance with the Windows service.

Alternatively, you can do this with [oradim](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTQRF/create.htm#sthref219), e.g:

```
oradim -edit -sid ORCL -startmode manual
```

The Windows service should be set to start automatically, and with the above setting, the database instance will not start with it.